# MTurk HIT with ReactJS publish error

Tags: reactjs, amazon-web-services, mechanicalturk

I am trying to create a HIT with ReactJS but I can not publish it.

The application is fairly big and when I create the project, the layout preview looks fine.

The only error I can see from the requester sandbox appears after I finish my project. I click the project and it returns

> Layout ID: Unavailable. There was an error creating your HIT layout.

How can I get more information to track down the issue? The project is closed source yet but what we do is:

1- create React App with `create-react-app`

2- build it and inline all code into `index.html`

3- Copy all content from `index.html` into the design layout.

Note in the `index.html` we add "dummy form" that is not used so it doesn't complain that there is no form available to submit the answer. We create the form in React at a later point.

I understand I provide little information but please advise what else would be helpful.

Is there a starter React application for `mturk` I could learn from?

Best,

Comment: Hey, Nicolas. Did you figure out how to solve your problem?

Comment: No, not really I kind of dropped it as it is currently a low priority for me. It seems there may be a limit on the size (in kb) of a layout...